# Running multiple functions of Runnable subclass (not only run())

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Is it possible to run other function of a subclass of Runnable threaded?

e.g.:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{

@Override
public void run()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        System.out.println("\t\t" + i);
}

public void somethingElse(int amount)
{
    String tabs = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        tabs += "\t";

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(tabs + i);
}
```

Can I run somethingElse() and other functions like it in another thread (other than the main one)?

I tried this:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread("New Thread") {
        public void run(){  
            MyRunnable x = new MyRunnable();
            x.somethingElse(1);
        }
    }; 

    Thread threadTwo = new Thread("New Thread") {
        public void run(){  
            MyRunnable x = new MyRunnable();
            x.somethingElse(2);
        }
    }; 

    thread.start();
    threadTwo.start();
```

But is this a correct way to solve it?

Comment: You want to execute run and somethingElse in different threats or in the same threat (not main)?

Comment: In the same thread, not the main one.
I'm implementing a database and I would like all of the queries to execute in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to create two different `Runnable` objects, each with its own definition of the `run()` method.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable1());
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable2());
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Java can only run a thread by executing the `run()` method on a `Runnable` implementation, or a subclass of `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code never execute `MyRunnable.run()`. Consider this

```
 MyRunnable r1 = new MyRunnable () ;
 r1.somethingElse(1); 
 Thread t1 = new Thread(r1,"Thread-R1") ;
 t2.start();
```

You could invoke any methods in a thread instance (MyRunnable in youre case) before you giving it to thread pool. Once thread is started, consider about synchronization.